# Exact search query with Elastica QueryBuilder

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm having a problem with an Elastica QueryBuilder exact search in a Symfony app. The Elastica version is 2.1, which depends on Elasticsearch 1.5.2. I'm searching an index where one of the fields is mapped as

```
majors:
    type: string
   index : not_analyzed
```

The field is a student's major that can have one or more words, such as "Ancient History".

The query is set up like this:

```
/** @var  ElasticaFactory $ef */
protected $ef;
public function __construct(ElasticaFactory $ef)
{
  $this->ef = $ef;
}

$query = $this->ef->createQuery();
$qb = $this->ef->createQueryBuilder();
$bool = $qb->filter()->bool();

$query->setQuery(
     $qb->query()->filtered(
          $qb->query()->term(),
          $bool->addShould(
              $qb->filter()->term(
                  array('majors' => $params['majors'])
              )
          )
     )
 );
```

When I run this query, I get a SearchPhaseExecutionException error. The full text of the error message is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A25e.png). 
Stack trace shows the full contents of the request:

```
Client ->request ('students/_search', 'GET', array('query' => array('filtered' => array('query' => array('term' => array()), 'filter' => array('bool' => array('should' => array(array('term' => array('majors' => 'Ancient Studies')))))))), array('from' => '0', 'size' => '10'))
in /vagrant/persona/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Search.php at line 455
```

When I set up the query as a "match" below, it works with no errors:

```
$query->setQuery(
    $qb->query()->filtered(
         $qb->query()->match('majors', $params['majors']),
         $bool
    )
);
```

However, a match query returns too many irrelevant results. I need specifically an exact search query.

Next, in order to eliminate any issues with Elastica, I converted the query into a raw ES query, like this:

```
$query->setRawQuery(
     array(
         'query' => array(
            'filtered' => array(
                'query' => array(
                    'term' => array()), 
                'filter' => array(
                    'bool' => array(
                        'should' => array(
                            array(
                                'term' => array(
                                    'majors' => 'Art History'
                                     )
                                  )
                             )
                        )
                   )
              )
         )
     )
);
```

This gave me the same error message as quoted above. Looks like there is a problem with the query itself, and not with Elastica.
When I rearranged the query to exactly follow the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_filter_with_text) as below, it returned no results, even though matching records were present

```
$query->setRawQuery(
            array(
                'query' => array(
                    'filtered' => array(
                        'filter' => array(
                            'term' => array(
                                'majors' => 'Art History'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of ES and Elastica are you using?

Comment: @Val, I'm using Elastica 2.1, which depends on Elasticsearch 1.5.2. That's a great question, I added this to the post.